# Свернуть и развернуть текст по нажатию на иконку

Tags: html, css, responsive

Есть текст который в мобильной версии разворачивается по нажатию иконки `+` и сворачивается по нажатию `-`. Я добавил 3 точки, но после нажатия на `+` текст разворачивается и мне нужно чтобы эти 3 точки исчезли, но они остаются. Как это решить? Я добавил класс `point` и в CSS сделал, но не работает. В чем проблема?
Вот HTML:

```
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.  
<span class="point">...</span>

    <input id="read-more-state-1" class="read-more-state" type="checkbox">
    <span class="read-more-target">
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    </span>
    <label for="read-more-state-1" class="read-more-button">
    <span class="read-more-button-icon"></span>
    </label>
    </p>
```

Вот CSS:

```
.read-more-state {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-button {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {   
  .read-more-target {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    transition: .25s ease;
  }

      .point {
display: none;
}

  .read-more-button {
    display: block;
    margin: 1em auto 0;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    background: url(img/arrow%20grad.svg);
    background-size: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .read-more-state:checked + .read-more-target {
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: inherit;
  }

  .read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-button {
    background: url(img/arrow%20up%20grad.svg);
    background-size: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Элемент `point` по умолчанию должен быть скрыт;
2. На мобилках делаем его `inline`;
3. Селектором `.read-more-state:checked ~ .point` скрываем точки, если чекбокс в активном состоянии;
4. Правим немного разметку, чтобы `point` был после чекбокса.

```css
.read-more-state {
    display: none;
}

.read-more-button {
    display: none;
    outline: 1px solid red;
}

.point {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .read-more-target {
        opacity: 0;
        font-size: 0;
        transition: .25s ease;
    }

    .point {
        display: inline;
    }

    .read-more-button {
        display: block;
        margin: 1em auto 0;
        border-radius: 0.25em;
        width: 1em;
        height: 1em;
        background: url(img/arrow%20grad.svg);
        background-size: cover;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-target {
        opacity: 1;
        font-size: inherit;
    }

    .read-more-state:checked ~ .point {
        display: none;
    }

    .read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-button {
        background: url(img/arrow%20up%20grad.svg);
        background-size: cover;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
    type specimen book.

    <input id="read-more-state-1" class="read-more-state" type="checkbox">

    <span class="point">...</span>

    <span class="read-more-target">
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    </span>
    
    <label for="read-more-state-1" class="read-more-button">
        <span class="read-more-button-icon"></span>
    </label>
</p>
```